# Error 301Moved Permanently on web server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I successfully run the  code on localhost. but same code on server i get error 301 permanently removed Moved Permanently. i use post request. my code is below.

```
$(function(){

        $("#search_text").keyup(function(e){
            var sVal = $(this).val();

            $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
            $.post('http://localhost/website/index.php/search/ajaxResults',{Search:sVal},function(data){

                             //my code here
            });

    });
});
```

its done successfully.

but same thing on web sever with below code:

```
$(function(){

        $("#search_text").keyup(function(e){
            var sVal = $(this).val();

            $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
            $.post('http://schoolanduniversity.com/index.php/search/ajaxResults',{Search:sVal},function(data){

                             //my code here
            });

    });
});
```

i get error 301

Comment: Can you explain what the `/website` part on your localhost is?

Comment: this is directory which has all file inside it

Comment: on the local it works fine, but when requesting any remote page, console shows 301 permanent redirect error and doesn't fetch any result....

Comment: did you try to put www.?

Comment: Gustonez : yes still not work

Answer (score 1):

thats because this url:

```
http://schoolanduniversity.com/index.php/search/ajaxResults
```

redirects to this url:

```
http://www.schoolanduniversity.com/index.php/search/ajaxResults
```

the DNS configuration of `schoolanduniversity.com` is to redirect to `www.schoolanduniversity.com`, just that.

if you change your url to put the `www` on front it should work

the `error code 301` is not an error, it is more like an warning, like

> You are tring to access thispage.com, but the server has moved to thatpage.com, please, next time use thatpage.com

for more info check here: [HTTP/1.1: Status Code Definitions # error code 301](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2)